# Convert DateTime to Double

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime, charts, zooming

I've created a DateTime value from an item being clicked in a listBox. It's in the format `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss`. I'm want to zoom in on a ten minute period with the clicked event in the middle. My current code is as follows (where zoom_time is the DateTime to zoom to on my chart;

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = (Convert.ToDouble(zoom_time.AddMinutes(-5)));
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = (Convert.ToDouble(zoom_time.AddMinutes(5)));
```

This breaks saying

> "invalid cast from DateTime to double"

Any ideas guys?

Comment: because you are trying to cast a `DateTime` to a `double`, which you cannot do like that. What `double` value are you expecting to get from the `DateTime`? Give an example of input and output values that you want

Answer (score 16):

You can use `DateTime.ToOADate()`, if you mean ole automation date by double

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for that!

For reference, the following works best;

```
            double start = (zoom_time.AddMinutes(-1)).ToOADate();
            double end = (zoom_time.AddMinutes(1)).ToOADate();

            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = start;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the ToOADate() methode like the following:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = zoom_time.AddMinutes(-5).ToOADate();
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = zoom_time.AddMinutes(5).ToOADate();
```

**Edit:**

Should have refreshed my page before answering. :)

Answer (score 1):

`ToOADate()` method that is mentioned in other answers here is not accurate!

It's better to use this:

```
double timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
```

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44880654/1057791) where he loses precision when doing `DateTime.Now.AddTicks(1000).ToOADate()`, if the example there were changed to `(double)DateTime.Now.AddTicks(1000).Ticks` the precision is not lost.